# Connect Kafka with Postgres via Debezium JDBC sink connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I have the following use case:

- Postgres DB in running in Openshift Cluster with a DB `sampledb`. In `sampledb` there is a table "`Authors`" that has columns: `Id (primary Key), first_name, last_name`
- AMQ Streams Kafka Cluster running in Openshift Cluster with a KafkaTopic `postgres` which is linked to a Protobuf schema where the structure matches the table `Authors`.
- The Protobuf schema is stored in Confluent Schema Registry which is connected to AMQ Streams Kafka

Goal:
I want to sent a message with a new author to my topic "postgres" such that the table "Authors" in my Postgres will be updated.

Therefore I have configured:

**Kafka Connect cluster** with following configuration:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect # (1)
metadata:
  name: postgres-connect
  namespace: amq-streams
  annotations:
    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true" # (2)
spec:
  replicas: 1 # (3)
  authentication: # (4)
    type: tls
    certificateAndKey:
      certificate: user.crt
      key: user.key
      secretName: amq-connect-user
  bootstrapServers: <AMQ Streams Kafka URL> # (5)
  tls: # (6)
    trustedCertificates:
      - secretName: amq-streams-cluster-ca-cert
        certificate: ca.crt
  config: # (7)
    group.id: postgres-connect-cluster
    offset.storage.topic: postgres-connect-offsets
    config.storage.topic: postgres-connect-configs
    status.storage.topic: postgres-connect-status
    # -1 means it will use the default replication factor configured in the broker
    config.storage.replication.factor: -1    
    offset.storage.replication.factor: -1
    status.storage.replication.factor: -1
    key.converter: io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
    key.converter.schema.registry.url: <URL Schema Registry>
    value.converter: io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
    value.converter.schema.registry.url: <URL Schema Registry>
    key.converter.schemas.enable: true
    value.converter.schemas.enable: true
  build: # (8)
    output: # (9)
      type: docker
      image: quay.io/namespace/postgres-connect-cluster:latest
      pushSecret: cr-image-pull-push-secret
    plugins: # (10)
      - name: kafka-connect-protobuf-converter
        artifacts:
          - type: jar
            url: https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-protobuf-converter/7.4.0/kafka-connect-protobuf-converter-7.4.0.jar
      - name: debezium-jdbc-connector
        artifacts:
          - type: tgz
            url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-jdbc/2.3.0.Final/debezium-connector-jdbc-2.3.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz
  resources: # (12)
    requests:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: 2Gi
    limits:
      cpu: "2"
      memory: 2Gi
  logging: # (13)
    type: inline
    loggers:
      log4j.rootLogger: "INFO"
  template: # (19)
    pod:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: cr-image-pull-push-secret
```

**KafkaConnector** instance with configuration parameters:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: jdbc-postgres-sink-connector
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  topics:
    - postgres
  config:
    connector.class: io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
    connection.url: jdbc:postgresql://<Postgres URL>:5432/sampledb
    connection.user: postgres
    insert.mode: upsert
    delete.enabled: true
    primary.key.mode: record_key
    primary.key.fields: id
    key.converter: io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
    key.converter.schema.registry.url: http://<schema registry URL>:8081
    value.converter: io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
    value.converter.schema.registry.url: http://<schema registry URL>:8081
    key.converter.schemas.enable: true
    value.converter.schemas.enable: true
```

Problem:
When I am sending messaged to my topic "postgres" nothing is added to my database table "Authors"

Does someone know what might be the problem?

Comment: 1) Debezium is not a Sink Connector. Your `class` value is therefore invalid. 2) Your connector config is using `sampledb` and you are sending to a `postgres` topic, so where does `Authors` string get used for any table name? (The topic and table name must match... Do you have a `postgres` table now?)

Comment: 1) Actually I am using a sink connector provided by Debezium. You can see it here: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/jdbc.html so my class value is correct. 2) But thanks for the hint that the topic and table name must match. This was not the case so far so I will re-test it with this.